# Error while sum of total in LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

I have a datatable's column as total. I need to take total sum of that column with help of linq and then need to show in console

I tried with below code but I am getting this error:

> Object doesn't contain definition for total.

```
var v = from s in dt.AsEnumerable()
        group s by 1 into g
        select new 
               {
                    total = g.Sum(x => x.Field<int>("Total") )
               };
dynamic vf = v;
Console.WriteLine(vf.total);
```

Comment: LINQ queries return `IEnumerable`s, not simple types. Why are you even using a LINQ query? Just sum directly:  `dt.AsEumerable().Sum(row => row.Field<int>("Total"))`.

Comment: kenneth i have more columns to sum as per group by so i tried with only one right now but i got this error

Comment: The result is of your query is `IEnumerable<T>` where `T` is going to be an instance of an anonymous type, with a single property named `total`, as defined in your projection. Assigning the value of `v` to a dynamic named `vf` changes nothing about this, except that the compiler no longer will tell you that there's no member named `total` - now the DLR is going to encounter the same error, later.  If you want the *first* total, `v.First().total` will work, if you want something else you need to define what exactly you're after.

Comment: Can you help me out here so how can I retrieve value of total in console?

Comment: Gotcha! Preston I can try with that thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
var vf = (from s in dt.AsEnumerable()
          group s by 1 into g
          select new 
          {
              total = g.Sum(x => x.Field<int>("Total") )
          }).FirstOrDefault();

Console.WriteLine(vf.total);
```